# Stackdriver Logging Advanced Filter Using Current Date/Time

Tags: filter, timestamp, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to create an exclusion filter which would exclude any logs older than 7 days.

It seems with `timestamp`, you must specify the actual date and time for this to work -- rather than use something like `timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)`

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Comment: Do you want to limit how long the logs are retained, or do you want to drop old logs that are being written late?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching by time from the filter expression is usually achieved by absolute timestamps. At present, computing relative time  is not supported in advanced filter.  You can determine timestamps in RFC 3339 format by using 'date' command from Linux, as per "Choose the right time period" [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#example_choose_the_right_time_period).

That being said, there is an internal Feature request filed for to include the relative timestamp ( e.g. "timestamp < now - 7 days" ) on the exclusion filter.

Comment: How can I find out the status on this Feature request? This is something that will be useful for us to use and I would like to implement it when it's ready.

Comment: You can file a new feature request on [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559764) so that the internal thread will be advised. However,  ETA or implementation of this feature at present is not guaranteed but rest assured that google strives on improving its product from feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Exclusion filters do not exclude logs that are already ingested. It only excludes new logs after the exclusion is created.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with @Summit, we cannot exclude the older logs that are already ingested to Stackdriver Logging.